# php: form pricing error

Tags: php, html, forms, scripting

As you can see I am trying to create a simple form which outputs the price in the php part. But i get these errors

**Notice:** `Undefined variable: result in /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w12024193/public_html/test/example2.php on line 3`

**Notice:** `Undefined index: booking in /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w12024193/public_html/test/example2.php on line 4`

**Warning:** `Division by zero in /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w12024193/public_html/test/example2.php on line 4`

Total cost is: 
**Notice:** `Undefined variable: result in /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w12024193/public_html/test/example2.php on line 18`
exculding VAT. Total cost is including VAT.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="example2.php">
<select name="booking">
<option value="Double Room">Double Room £50</option>
<option value="Twin Room">Twin Room £70</option>
<option value="Family Room">Family Room £100</option>
</select>

<select name="service">
 <option value="10">Yes £10</option>
 <option value="0">No</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="submit" action="example2.php" name="submit"><br />
</form>
```

PHP

```
$vresult = $result * 20%
$booking = $_GET["booking"];

if ($booking == "Double Room"){
$result = 50 + $_GET["service"];
}
else if($booking == "Twin Room"){
$result = 50 + $_GET["service"];
}
else if($booking == "Family Room"){
$result = 100 + $_GET["service"];
}
?>
 Total cost is <?php echo $result;?> exculding VAT.

 Total cost is <?php echo $vresult; ?> including VAT.
```

Comment: where is $result coming from??

Comment: Your `method="post"`, so examine `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Comment: It seems you are giving the PHP from line 3 onwards. What's happening in lines 1 and 2? Where is `$result` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** vresult should be after you defined $result, and calculate 20% extra with * 1.2 instead of * 20%;
**Second:** You need to use $_POST instead of $_GET
**Third:** $_POST['service'] can be altered, just check it before you output it

```
$booking = @$_POST["booking"];
$service = @$_POST["service"] == 10? 10 : 0;

if ($booking == "Double Room"){
   $result = 50 + $service;
}
else if($booking == "Twin Room"){
   $result = 50 + $service;
}
else if($booking == "Family Room"){
   $result = 100 + $service;
}
$vresult = $result * 1.2;
?>
 Total cost is <?php echo $result;?> exculding VAT.

 Total cost is <?php echo $vresult; ?> including VAT.
```

Comment: You also missed the `$result * 20%` issue.

Comment: A big chunk of code with no explanation is never a good answer.

Comment: ok this works, I noted all the errors, much appreciated everyone.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
$vresult = $result * 20%
```

The `%` character is the [modulus operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and as you are not using a second parameter nor a terminating `;` that leads to all kind of errors as php sees your line as:

```
$vresult = $result * 20 % $booking = $_GET["booking"];
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined (see below)
                          ^^^^^^^^ NULL leads to division by zero
```

You probably want:

```
$vresult = $result * 0.2;
```

And your form method is `POST` so your posted variables will be located in the `$_POST` array.

**Edit:** The price including 20% would of course be `1.2 * $result` and you calculate that **after** you have calculated the price.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll keep that noted.

Comment: Including VAT would be `* 1.2`, and not `* 0.2`. If you do `* 0.2` you calculate 20% of the price, with `* 1.2` you add 20% to the price.

Comment: @John True, the first lines were so wrong I did not read it all. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you need to move the line that computes the VAT

```
$vresult = $result * 20%
```

to AFTER you have actually computed the `$result` - so just before you close the PHP script. And you need to write it as

```
$vresult = $result * 0.2;
```

Comment: Just realized that @Jeroen had an almost identical answer... and he got there first.

Comment: Nice catch of the VAT calculation before the price calculation, I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 0):

`$result` is not defined. I am referencing the first line of php: `$vresult = $result * 20%`. If you are trying to set the `$result` based on the booking type you need to move the noted line below the code that sets `$result`

Also your form method is `POST` so you need to use `$_POST['booking']`

You are also missing a `;` after the first line of php

Comment: $result is used as a variable to echo the total cost calculated. What code would i need to put to define it for that purpose?

Answer (score -2):

when you open the file for the first time there is no form submitted and these  variables are not defined. 
you need to user isset() function before define them.